# How to use ACL with OAuth Authentication

Tags: php, oauth, acl

lets assume i have 2 different web application. SMSGate and VideoSite.

On both sites i use OAUTH authentication with own OAuth server (based on https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php)

I have user A and B, where A has access to both apps and B has access only to SMSGate.
How should i limit user B access to VideoSite application?

Via OAuth scope ? or with ACL inside each application ?

Thank's for response.